# Select attribute value but not if it is duplicated with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an OOXML file and I want to select w:document/w:body/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val values and only if w:p node has text. My problem is that I know how to take them all using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <DifferentStyles>
        <xsl:for-each select="w:document/w:body/w:p">
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val and w:r/w:t">
                <stylish>
                    <xsl:value-of select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val"/>
                </stylish>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </DifferentStyles>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that i don´t know how to not take into account if the value is the same. I have been investigating with the generate-id and key taks but I don´t understand them at all.
Here I attach you a short part of the OOXML file:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00E24C8B">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TitleHeading"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Index</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00E24C8B">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TitleHeading"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>-by-</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00E24C8B">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TitleHeading"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Cesar G.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00046C79">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="HeadingF"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="IntenseReference"/>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:color w:val="auto"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00E24C8B">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>referenced applications</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00046C79" w:rsidRDefault="00E24C8B">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="NumberedParagraph"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">This application</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

I want the next result:

```
<DifferentStyles>
   <stylish>TitleHeading</stylish>
   <stylish>Heading</stylish>
   <stylish>NumberedParagraph</stylish>
</DifferentStyles>
```

Thank you, I hope someone can help me!!

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0 then the `distinct-values()` function should provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following concise script to perform your task:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://dummy_w.com" xpath-default-namespace="http://dummy_w.com"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <DifferentStyles>
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(p/pPr[../r/t]/pStyle/@w:val)">
        <stylish><xsl:value-of select="."/></stylish>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DifferentStyles>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that:

- `xpath-default-namespace` allows to omit namespace
  specifications (except for attributes).
- The template can match only `body`.

How works the `select` clause in `for-each`:

- Find `p/pPr` nodes...
- which have an `r` neighbour with a `t` inside (`[../r/t]`),
- from them (I mean *pPr* nodes) take `pStyle` children,
- from them take `val` attribute,
- and finally, eliminate repetitions (`distinct-values`).

Or maybe you want these styles to be sorted? If you do, add
`<xsl:sort select="."/>` after `for_each`.

Comment: Yes but how can I do to know also if that w:p has w:r/w:t ? because I only want to select the style if it has.

Comment: Existence of `r` neighbour is checked in the predicate. I only initially missed `t` inside it. The correction was very simple (add `/t` after `/r` in the predicate).